# 12V to 220V modified sine wave inverter simulation

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, power-electronics, simulation, proteus

I simulated this circuit but got an unexpected signal. The result appears on the graph.
[image]
But I expected this result:

[image]

These pictures show my transformer and lamp settings:
[image]

[image]

The schematic and oscilloscope picture are taken from this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=urKi9OLDdCA

I mean, I don't understand. What's my mistake?

Comment: What is the voltage reference of the P1 graph? To measure voltage, you need to measure voltage between 2 points, yet it only seems to use 1 point

Comment: @Ferrybig I tried, but got a similar result

Comment: Please show a full and proper schematic of the design that you believe works. Also, explain what the coupling factor and turns ratio is for the transformer along with its primary inductance.

Comment: @ Andy aka
This link shows a complete schematic of the design.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1G1u_v8XEndqqBSyM5LBN8yDbqK4PYNsS                  Actually, I don't know the meaning of the terms, so I found ready-made values and used them.

Comment: Why have you got an inductor as the load (L1)?

Comment: @Andy aka I used a lamp as a load, but it is not important for me , it can be a resistor.

Comment: You should look at the primary waveforms to confirm the transformer is being driven correctly. I expect that the extra pulses are due to back emfs

Comment: @Andy aka I checked and there seems to be something wrong. How can I fix this or how can I find resources on this subject?

Comment: Try using a resistor for the load and, not one of value 100 kohm. Maybe 1 kohm

Comment: @Andy aka Thanks, it works now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The load was just too high in value and, back-emfs from the flux in the transformer are masking the true power output voltage waveform. From comments: -

> Try using a resistor for the load and, not one of value 100 kohm.
> Maybe 1 kohm – Andy aka

*> @Andy aka Thanks, it works now – Serkan Kaya*

Answer (score 0):

seems like discarge part of coil as in this transformer/circuit phase shifting is not used...  circuit use half phase of coil then leawes it to discharge itself... so simulator simulates discharge phase generated voltage mostlikely or sister coil generated shadow voltage or watewer its called. there is in reality 2 coils on 12 volts side...

Comment: how can I simulate this circuit?